# NSURLConnection is not working in NSBlockOperation while operation added to NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsoperationqueue

I am using NSURLConnection in NSBlockOperation and i am adding this operation to NSOperationQueue.But it is not working.When i am calling start method of NSBlockOperation then it working but it is not working when i am adding NSBlockOperation to NSOperationQueue.

please can anyone help me ???

```
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];

NSBlockOperation *operation1 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising"];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLConnection  *connection1 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    [connection1 start];
}];

NSBlockOperation *operation2 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json"];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


    NSURLConnection  *connection2 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    [connection2 start];
}];

[operation2 addDependency:operation1];

[operationQueue addOperation:operation1];
[operationQueue addOperation:operation2];
```

I have also implemented NSURLConnectionDataDelegate as:

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response

Please help
Thanks

Comment: *Why* are you using a NSOperationQueue and start (realy only *start*) the NSURLConnection in a block which executes on the NSOperationQueue? You may take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-SW12 **Scheduling Delegate Method Calls**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least two issues with your code:

1. You mustn't call `- (void)start` after `- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id < NSURLConnectionDelegate >)delegate`. It starts by itself.
2. `- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id < NSURLConnectionDelegate >)delegate` is asynchronous so you have to keep your operation alive all that time while it works as well as your operationQueue shouldn't be a "stack" variable.

How to fix it easily:

1. Use `+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error` inside your blockOperations. It blocks current thread while performing loading.

Example:

```
NSBlockOperation *operation2 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json"];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error];
}];
```

There are a lot of other approaches but first one should work perfectly well.

Comment: Thanks it is working.
But in my code what is the problem ? why NSURLConnectionDelegates are not hitting ? Is it because of runloop ? I have also tried
[connection1 scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [connection1 start]; 
but still delegates are not hitting.

Comment: The main problem of your code is when NSURLConnection starts working and is going to use NSURLConnectionDelegates calls the thread finishes and deallocates all its resources including your NSURLConnection. So to get calls from your NSURLConnection instance in that thread you have to add manual thread blocking while data is loading as well as unblocking it after it finishes. Also it is good to fix the issues I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
NSBlockOperation *operation1 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising"];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLConnection  *connection1 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    [connection1 scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [connection1 start];
}];
```

The reason for this is that NSURLConnection tries to deliver it's delegate updates on the run loop of the thread that it's been started on, in your case it's another thread, that backs up the queue of the NSOperationQueue, that thread might've been recycled by the time that your network call returns and there'll be no run loop to handle the source, thus you don't get your delegates hit. Using this approach you'll get these events on the main run loop, which is sure to be alive.

The way you use NSURLConnection is async, as opposed to the `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` way of using it, which is synchronous. Thus there's no point in starting it in another thread.

But if you're just trying to do async network communication, you can really simplify your code with the method `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` . That way you won't need to implement any delegates. The only issue you might have is if there's some sort of authentication, then you'll need the approach that you're on.

Comment: I understood what you have explained but [connection1 scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
 is not working. After putting this line delegates are not hitting.